# Why doesn't sd card show up as a bootable device?

Tags: boot, sd-card

I just installed Gentoo onto an SD card, not an the minimal ISO, the entire OS. I want to boot from the SD card, however it does not show up as a device to boot from, what should I do? Also how do I make it the default device to boot from?

Comment: why do you believe that your computer is capable of booting from an SD card?

Comment: I mean that is how raspberry pis work

Comment: are you booting a raspberry pi?

Comment: No I am booting an HP stream laptop

Comment: then it most likely will not boot from SD card ... if you plug in a blank USB thumb drive, then the thumb drive will show up in boot options ... put in a blank SD card and check the boot options ... it will most likely not be there

Comment: Some BIOSes can, while some can't. I have an old Asus EeeBox that can.

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment, you should first try:
http://multibootusb.org/page_download/
there is a package for Gentoo there.

Also I think you should use the sd-card on a usb adapter to let it be recognized thru usb.

To make it default, you should configure it thru grub. Or if you mean in a hardware way, you should setup the BIOS to look at it first, if possible at all.

Comment: I want to put it in the SD card slot not a USB port.